# Finding the average using mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I just started learning MySQL and I got these tables from [sqlzoo.net](http://sqlzoo.net)

```
game
id        mdate            stadium                team1 team2
1001    8 June 2012     National Stadium, Warsaw    POL GRE
1002    8 June 2012     Stadion Miejski (Wroclaw)   RUS CZE
1003    12 June 2012    Stadion Miejski (Wroclaw)   GRE CZE
1004    12 June 2012    National Stadium, Warsaw    POL RUS
...

goal
matchid teamid  player               gtime
1001    POL     Robert Lewandowski     17
1001    GRE     Dimitris Salpingidis   51
1002    RUS     Alan Dzagoev           15
1001    RUS     Roman Pavlyuchenko     82
...
```

I am using the following code to show the match id where the goal time is more than 20

```
SELECT goal.matchid 
FROM game, goal
WHERE game.id = goal.matchid AND goal.gtime > 20
```

That worked well, although, now I want to show the match id where the goal time average is more than 20 but I'm at a loss.

---

**1 more question!**

For example I have 1 more table: coach(id, teamid, coachname) I want to find all goals between 25-50 (gtime) by showing all columns in goal and coachname column in coach

```
SELECT matchid, goal.teamid, player, gtime, coachname
FROM goal JOIN coach ON (goal.teamid=coach.teamid)
WHERE gtime BETWEEN 25 AND 50
```

That worked well but I'm wondering if there is any simpler code so I don't have to write all the columns from goal table. Thanks!

Comment: a question for time is better..

Comment: You might get better answers by being more specific to a single problem

Comment: Some systems let you say things like `select goal.*` I can't remember where MySQL falls on that one. It's generally good to alias your tables and then qualify the columns. The biggest benefit to me is not having to look it up when you forget later and for clarity in forums like this where we didn't ever know in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be you are looking for somethig like this

```
SELECT goal.matchid 
FROM game, goal
WHERE game.id = goal.matchid 
having avg(goal.gtime) > 20 
group by goal.matchid
```

Comment: That's great! I haven't learned about 'having' clause before. I really just started learning. Thank you very much!

Comment: @scaisEdge When you include only rows with `gtime > 20` then the average is automatically greater than twenty. The query is wrong.

Comment: @shawnt00 is an having not a where.. the eval is on the result value and not on the row value

Comment: @scaisEdge You are filtering rows in the `where` clause first and then finding the average. It's the `where` clause that's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't even need the `game` table and the join for this result.

```
select matchid
from goal
having avg(gtime) > 20
group by matchid
```

Another of the answers retained the `where` clause filter on `gtime > 20`. It you do that then all the matches with goals after the 20th minute will have averages that qualify on that limited data set. In other words the average of all values greater than 20 is going to exceed 20 also. The `avg()` aggregate only applies to rows that make it past the `where` conditions.

Comment: Ohhh that's right thanks! My question was wrong, I was gonna find the mdate from game table so I use the game table.

Answer (score -1):

You can use AVG() function to find Average.

```
SELECT goal.matchid
FROM game, goal
WHERE AVG(goal.gtime) > 20
```

I couldn't recall simpler code for second one.

Comment: You cannot use aggregate functions in the where clause. Beside that you are doing a cross join between game and goal, and you do not have a group by clause